# How to rename file names - replacing underscores with spaces - in a shell command line script

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to rename all files in a folder replacing underscores with spaces.

```
i.e. this_is_a_test --> this is a test
```

but somehow I'm messing up the quoting

```
> for file in * ; do echo mv -v $file $(echo $file | sed 's/_/\\ /g') ; done
mv -v this_is_a_test this\ is\ a\ test
```

that looks OK, but if I remove the 'echo' `mv` complains as if the backslashes were removed

```
> for file in * ; do mv -v $file $(echo $file | sed 's/_/\\ /g') ; done
mv: target ‘test’ is not a directory
```

Can someone point out the error of my ways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a minor mistake. Use `"$newfile"` instead of only `$newfile`. You need to use `"`

Here is the correct one.

```
for file in * ; do mv -v "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/_/\\ /g')" ; done
```

If you have filename `this_is_a_test` it will rename file to `this\ is\ a\ test`.

In case if you want to rename the file to `this is a test`. Use the code below,

```
for file in * ; do mv -v "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/_/ /g')" ; done
```

It is a good practise to use variables inside `""` while you writing good shell script.

Comment: Old answer, however just for clarity since its becoming popular again, this will break filenames containing newlines

Answer (score 8):

Using `rename`:

```
rename -n 's/_/ /g' *
```

If everything is ok, remove the `-n` switch:

```
rename 's/_/ /g' *
```

```bsh
~/tmp$ tree
.
├── file
├── file_1
├── file_2
├── file_3
└── file_with_underscores

0 directories, 5 files
~/tmp$ rename 's/_/ /g' *
~/tmp$ tree
.
├── file
├── file 1
├── file 2
├── file 3
└── file with underscores

0 directories, 5 files
```

Comment: The question gets an unusual popularity =) +1

Comment: I like your tree command … Installed =)

Comment: Only true for the Perl `rename` utility. Does not work for the rename included in `util-linux`.

Comment: why is rename not available on macos even though it's linux-based?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `mv -v "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/_/\\ /g')"` you can use a much simpler command `mv "$f" "${f//_/ }"`.

To add it in your script:

```
for f in * ; do mv "$f" "${f//_/ }" ; done
```

And that's it.

Comment: This is pretty much ok, but it will break filenames containing newlines

Comment: @kos no it won't. Shell globs can deal with newlines with no problem. Souravac's answer will break on newlines but only because of `sed`.

Comment: @terdon I tought it would have break on the expansion pretty much like Souravac's answer on the replacement, that's true. @ Maythux Apologies, +1 then

Answer (score 2):

Use the `find` and `rename` command:

```
find <your_start_folder> -type f -regex ".*_+.*" -exec rename 's/_/ /g' {}  \;
```

This command renames all file with a `_` in the filename recursively.

*Explanation*

- `-regex ".*_+.*"`

  Find all files with at least one `_` in the filename
- `_`

  Replace all occurrences of `_` …
- … with a space character ( )

---

*Example*

```
% ls -Rog
.:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 4096 Jun 15 17:39 foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1    0 Jun 15 17:34 foo_bar

./foo:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Jun 15 17:32 foo_bar

% find . -type f -regex ".*_+.*" -exec rename 's/_/ /g' {} \;

% ls -Rog                                                                 
.:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 4096 Jun 15 17:40 foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1    0 Jun 15 17:34 foo bar

./foo:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Jun 15 17:32 foo bar
```

Comment: Hmmm this works only if there are maximum two underscores in the filename.

Comment: @kos DOH I'm getting old

Comment: @kos ok, fixed =)

Comment: +1 for a recursive way, however OP's script applies also to directories. Also `-regex` is not really needed here, `-name "*_*"` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk + for loop version:

`for filename in *; do NEWNAME=$(echo "$filename" | awk '{gsub("_"," "); print}'); mv "$filename" "$NEWNAME";done`

And here it is in action

```
$ ls                                                                                                                                                  

$ echo "TEST" | tee {foo,bar}_{yolo,swag}_{whatever,else}.txt                                                                                         
TEST

$ ls
bar_swag_else.txt      bar_yolo_else.txt      foo_swag_else.txt      foo_yolo_else.txt
bar_swag_whatever.txt  bar_yolo_whatever.txt  foo_swag_whatever.txt  foo_yolo_whatever.txt

$ for filename in *; do NEWNAME=$(echo "$filename" | awk '{gsub("_"," "); print}'); mv "$filename" "$NEWNAME";done                                    

$ ls
bar swag else.txt      bar yolo else.txt      foo swag else.txt      foo yolo else.txt
bar swag whatever.txt  bar yolo whatever.txt  foo swag whatever.txt  foo yolo whatever.txt
```

To account for newlines and possible renaming of directories, here's the typical IFS + find + read + while loop construct. Once suggestion through, run first the version with `find . -type d -print0`, because if you start renaming files first, and a subdirectory contains underscore, the filename won't be changed. In short, take care of directories and subdirectories first, then take care of the files

```
$ ls
file_bar_swag.txt  file_bar_yolo.txt  file_test_swag.txt  file_test_yolo.txt  foo_bar_swag.txt  foo_bar_yolo.txt  foo_test_swag.txt  foo_test_yolo.txt  tester_dir

$ ls tester_dir/                                                                                                                                                                                         
ber_sweg_elze.txt  ber_sweg_whut.txt  ber_yelo_elze.txt  ber_yelo_whut.txt  fee_sweg_elze.txt  fee_sweg_whut.txt  fee_yelo_elze.txt  fee_yelo_whut.txt

$  find . -type d -print0 | while IFS="" read -r -d "" filename ; do NEWNAME=$(echo "$filename" | awk '{gsub("_"," "); print}'); mv "$filename" "$NEWNAME";done 
mv: ‘.’ and ‘./.’ are the same file

$ ls
file_bar_swag.txt  file_bar_yolo.txt  file_test_swag.txt  file_test_yolo.txt  foo_bar_swag.txt  foo_bar_yolo.txt  foo_test_swag.txt  foo_test_yolo.txt  tester dir

$  find . -type f -print0 | while IFS="" read -r -d "" filename ; do NEWNAME=$(echo "$filename" | awk '{gsub("_"," "); print}'); mv "$filename" "$NEWNAME";done                                          
mv: ‘./.yolo’ and ‘./.yolo’ are the same file

$ ls
file bar swag.txt  file bar yolo.txt  file test swag.txt  file test yolo.txt  foo bar swag.txt  foo bar yolo.txt  foo test swag.txt  foo test yolo.txt  tester dir
```

As you can see, there's a small problem - because the find command lists current directory as well ( symbolized with a .), the command will create a byproduct - a file with a leading dot.

Adding `! -path .` when you deal with directories solves the problem

```
$ find . ! -path .  -type d -print0 | while IFS="" read -r -d "" filename ; do NEWNAME=$(echo "$filename" | awk '{gsub("_"," "); print}'); mv "$filename" "$NEWNAME";done                                

$ find .  -type f -print0 | while IFS="" read -r -d "" filename ; do NEWNAME=$(echo "$filename" | awk '{gsub("_"," "); print}'); mv "$filename" "$NEWNAME";done                                          

$ ls
file bar swag.txt  file bar yolo.txt  file baz swag.txt  file baz yolo.txt  foo bar swag.txt  foo bar yolo.txt  foo baz swag.txt  foo baz yolo.txt  tester dir

$ ls "tester dir"
file bar.txt  file baz.txt  foo bar.txt  foo baz.txt

$ ls -a
.  ..  file bar swag.txt  file bar yolo.txt  file baz swag.txt  file baz yolo.txt  foo bar swag.txt  foo bar yolo.txt  foo baz swag.txt  foo baz yolo.txt  tester dir
```