# Remove dashes from filenames

Tags: bash, ubuntu-mate

This removes spaces in filenames.

How can I also remove dashes - ?

```
rename "s/ //g" *
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename file names - replacing underscores with spaces - in a shell command line script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390631/how-to-rename-file-names-replacing-underscores-with-spaces-in-a-shell-comman)

Comment: Underscore is different from a dash.

Comment: An x character is also different from a y character, and an empty string is different from a space character, however the command to replace one character with another character has the same form in both cases which makes them duplicates because of their form.

Comment: Although I don't think the difference between an `_` and a `-` is significant here, the answers to [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390631/how-to-rename-file-names-replacing-underscores-with-spaces-in-a-shell-comman) don't show how to remove multiple different characters, and this is asking how to remove spaces and *also* hyphens. [The answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1257880/22949) on this question does show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rename 's/-//g' *
```

doesn't work when any of the filenames begins with a dash, because it is then interpreted as initiating an option.
You need to use the -- flag, which terminates the option string:

```
rename -- 's/-//g' *
```

Answer (score 2):

`rename` in Ubuntu is a `perl` tool, it uses [`perl` syntax](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace):

```
s/regex/replacement/modifiers
```

In your case:

- *regex* is a space (what you want to replace)
- *replacement* is empty (you want to replace with nothing)
- *modifiers* is `g` (don't stop after first regex match)

So you need to understand how to edit the regex to match dashes:

Simply use this to remove dashes:

```
rename 's/-//g' *
```

But if you want to remove both dashes and space, you may use [character classes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Using-character-classes).

So this  will do it for you:

```
rename 's/[- ]//g' *
```

---

Please note, when any of the filenames begins with a `-`, it won't work. Please see [@BillPoser's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1330638/631600).